# Type inference of values contained in strings stored in a list

Tags: python, csv, types

I am trying to figure out how to do some nice type inference on the columns of a CSV file.
Are there any libraries that might tell me, for example, that a column contains only integers?
All values are of course available in string format.

I will write my own tool if nothing of this sort already exists, but it seems weird to me that such a basic task does not have a library counterpart somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do the straightforward approach?

- if all values can be parsed as integers, to column is integers
- otherwise, if all values can be parsed as doubles, to column is doubles
- otherwise, the column is all strings

The reason why there is no library for this is probably because it's trivial to implement using the existing string to int and string to double conversion functions.

Answer (score 1):

[Regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) are good for that, in Python, you could use something like this:

```
import re

def str_is_num(s):
    number_pattern = re.compile("-?^\d+(\.\d+)?$")
    return re.match(number_pattern, s) != None
```

To check whether a cell is a number, you can evaluate `str_is_num(cell)`